# Recording keypress and clicking the link that corresponds to the pressed characters

Tags: javascript

I'm recording which keys are being pressed. After pressing two keys, the first link that matches the two characters will be highlighted. After pressing one more key, the link that corresponds to those three characters will be clicked.

```js
let keys = []

document.addEventListener('keypress', event => {
  if (event.key === ' ') return

  keys.push(event.key)

  const selector = 'a'
  let text = keys.join('')
  let element = [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)]
    .find(elements => elements.textContent.includes(text))

  if (keys.length === 2) {
    if (!element) {
      keys = []
      return
    }

    const highlightColor = '#f2e1c2'
    element.style.borderBottom = `2px solid ${highlightColor}`
    element.scrollIntoView({
      block: "center"
    })
  }

  if (keys.length === 3) {
    if (!element) {
      keys = []
      return
    }

    element.click()
    keys = []
  }
})
```

As you can see, there are a lot of if statements. [Some people](https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/clean-code-javascript#avoid-conditionals) suggest that you should avoid conditionals. Should I follow that advice here? If so, how should I remove them the conditionals?

Comment: @TobySpeight Is the title fine now?

Comment: Looks much better - thank you!

Comment: It'd be cool to be able to run this on some sample HTML in the snippet to see the behavior.

Answer (score 2):

### Warning `keypress`

The [keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) event has been depreciated. Using it means that your code can just stop working at any time without warning.

See [keypress](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event) page for alternatives. I will assume you use [keydown](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event)

### Style

First some optional style points that will help reduce the chance of bugs

- Delimit all code blocks. Eg `if (event.key === ' ') return` should be `if (event.key === ' ') { return }`
- Use semicolon to end all ambiguous lines. See rewrite.
- Use constants for variables that do not change. See rewrite.

General style points

- Empty arrays rather than reassign arrays. See rewrite.
- Don't repeat code. You empty the key array in 3 places, only needs to be done once.
- Use class name to change style rather than assign directly to the style property.

### UI Problems

This code is very user unfriendly.

A list of problems

- You use the [KeyboardEvent.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key)  property to define the search term. However many keys will be named keys rather than a character. eg `Tab`, `Shift`

  Hitting any of the non character keys will create a non intuitive search.
- You highlight anchor elements that match. However if the match does not complete the highlight is left in place.

  You need to remove the highlight from anchors that don't complete the matched keys.
- (ignoring above point) You only highlight one anchor even if the search would match more than one.

  The user will see the functionality as broken if you don't highlight all matching anchors.

  If you highlight all matches you also need to proved a way to toggle the current focused highlighted option. EG use the Tab key to cycle matches
- It is possible to accidentally hit keys (Cat on the keyboard).

  With only 3 keys required you redirect the user's page too easily. This is very poor UI practice.

  Better to wait for confirmation (eg user hits "enter")  before navigating
- Don't limit the search to 3 keys strokes. Let the user enter as many keys as needed to make the search term unique.

  Automatically reset the search term only when there are no matches.
- There is no way to cancel the search (apart from adding a 3 characters that do not match an anchors text.

  Give the user a way to cancel (eg clear the search on the Escape key)
- The match is maintained indefinitely.

  If the page has a highlighted match the user can come back in hours and if a key is hit that matches the anchor it will navigate.

  Add a search timeout that resets the search term after some timeout

There are more behavioral problems but they should become non issues if you address the points above.

I will say that your code is unfit and should never be released into the wild.

### Rewrite

The rewrite keeps the same functionality and is only an example of a cleaner style. It is **NOT** an example of how to implement this type of feature.

I would never use this code due to the many UI problems (as pointed out above)

**Note** this function assumes that the CSS class `highlightAnchor` has been defined

**Note** A slight behavior change is that a 3 character string match will also highlight and scroll into view.

**Note** If the page contains 100s of anchors you should consider moving the [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) out of the [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) callback

```
;(()=> {
    const keys = []
    const anchors = [...document.querySelectorAll("a")];
    anchors.length && document.addEventListener('keydown', event => {
        if (event.key !== ' ') { 
            keys.length = keys.length >= 3 ? 0 : keys.length;
            keys.push(event.key);
            const match = anchors.find(a => a.textContent.includes(keys.join('')));     
            if (match && keys.length >= 2) {
                match.classList.add("highlightAnchor");
                match.scrollIntoView({block: "center"})
                search.length === 3 && match.click();
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

### If statements

Code without conditional branching does not need a computer to run it.

There is nothing wrong with `if` (and like branching instructions, `if`, `else`, `switch case`, `while`, ...). They can not be avoided, they can only be hidden via syntax tricks / hacks.

OMDG The linked example you give of [bad practice](https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/clean-code-javascript#avoid-conditionals) should be read with a pinch of salt (oceans worth if you ask me) The "bad" V "good" example are completely unrelated and it is quite laughable.